# In App Purchase( How user Subscribe to Single product at a time)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have created the product list of 3 product of type SUBSCRIPTIONS.

> Required

When the user subscribe to another product, if their is any the Subscription of 
previous product it automatically get cancelled, 
and user get subscribe to newly selected product.

> Problem

The user get subscription of 2 products at a time which is wrong.

> I have search it, but found the solution that user manually need to
>   Unsubscribe the product in Play Store Account --> Subscription
>   setting.  is there is any another way to Unsubscribe previuos Product
>   if user subscribe new Product of type subscription.

Answer (score 1):

> Subscription Upgrade/Downgrade

With the In-app Billing API, users can upgrade or downgrade a subscription during its active period. When the user does this, the active subscription is canceled and a new subscription is created. ***The unused balance of the old subscription is applied on a pro-rated basis to the new subscription.*** The first billing period for the new subscription begins after that balance is used up.

> Subscription Cancellation

Users can view the status of all of their subscriptions and cancel them if necessary from the My Apps screen in the Play Store app. Currently, the ***In-app Billing API does not provide support for programmatically canceling subscriptions*** from inside the purchasing app.

In addition to client-side API calls, you can use the server-side API for [cancelling a subscription](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/cancel) programattically. This call cancels a user's subscription purchase but remains valid until its expiration time.

Comment: yes, i read this thing, the user needs to manually unsubscribe the product. 
is there any other way to unsubscribe product in code.

Comment: or we create the group of product ids in play console, so that if the user can subscribe only one product at a time.

Comment: Read through the **Subscription Cancellation section** I written carefully till end.

Comment: In-app Billing API does not provide support for programmatically canceling subscriptions from inside the purchasing app.

In addition to client-side API calls, you can use the server-side API for cancelling a subscription programattically.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html

please read the 6th point, user wont be charged 2nd time as per android Documentation, read below.

> Users can upgrade or downgrade a subscription in the middle of a
>   subscription period. The old subscription's cost is pro-rated, and the
>   unused portion is applied to the replacement subscription.

Comment: I already read this thing but the problem is this in the case of subscription products. the new product gets subscripted, and the previous subscription not gets affected.